# Want to redirect pages from old domain to new domain using 301 redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two domains 
1. rameshmehndi.com(old)
2. mehndigoa.com(new)

I want to redirect some pages from old domain to new domain with 301 redirect

ex. http://rameshmehndi.com/aboutus.aspx to http://mehndigoa.com/about-us/

how can I do that using web.config

```
    <configuration>
  <location path="services.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="products.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

this above code is not working

Comment: May be, replace config values with actual ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS7 or .Net 301 Redirects from 1 domain to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046081/iis7-or-net-301-redirects-from-1-domain-to-another)

Comment: In addition to following the link above and using the solution, you need to have the [IIS Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed on your server.